# Why do videos turn gray after transcoding?

Tags: video, transcoding, aws-media-convert

I have used the AWS service MediaConvert to convert videos into another format before, and sometimes the first half-minute of the video will be just grey, but it will get better as the video goes on. A example frame provided below. If the object in the video moves a lot, it gets more color back.

Today I came acrossed using opencv to convert mp4 into avi, and the same thing happends again. Does anyone know why this is happening and how to prevent it?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Do you mind posting the output settings you are using?

For Video Quality settings, I would say make sure your settings contain the following:

Scene change detection is enabled 
Adaptive Quantization is set to Auto
Set Profile to High for AVC, Main/High for HEVC or Main for MPEG-2 video codecs 
Set reference frames to 3 
Set b-frames to 2.

If you are seeing grey frames at the beginning of encodes, also may be worth running the following ffprobe [1] command on your input source to make sure your first frame is a key frame (IDR) [2].

`ffprobe -i testme.mp4 -select_streams v:0 -show_frames  | grep -E '(FRAME|key_frame=|pict_type=)'`

Output will look something like this:

```
[FRAME]
key_frame=1
pict_type=I
[/FRAME]
[FRAME]
key_frame=0
pict_type=B
[/FRAME]
[FRAME]
key_frame=0
pict_type=B
[/FRAME]
[FRAME]
key_frame=0
pict_type=B
[/FRAME]
[FRAME]
....
```

== Resources ==
[1] FFPROBE Download: https://ffmpeg.org/download.html 
[2] What is an IDR Frame: https://streaminglearningcenter.com/articles/everything-you-ever-wanted-to-know-about-idr-frames-but-were-afraid-to-ask.html